# Distinct list of file types in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a one-liner in Powershell that lists all filetypes in a folder (and its sub-folders).

I've got this so far:

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Audio -Recursive | Select-Object PSParentPath, Extension | Export-Csv D:\Test.csv
```

However, I'd like to do better and display, for each folder, every found extension only once.

For example, let's say I have ten mp3 files and 1 jpg file in D:\Audio\foo and 5 flac files and 1 txt file in D:\Audio\bar. I'd like the output to be :

- foo .mp3
- foo .jpeg
- bar .flac
- bar .txt

I guess I should use Get-Unique but how do I specify it on the Extension property and NOT on the Path property?

Comment: Are your subfolders only 1 deep?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just add -Unique to Select-Object:

```
Get-Childitem -Recurse | Select-Object PSParentPath,Extension -Unique
```

(Also, DirectoryName might be better than PSParentPath here)

Comment: Perfect! This one does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @D3vtr0n Yeah, I'd personally write it like `ls -rec | select PSParentPath,Extension -u`, but I shy away from aliases when answering questions.

Comment: @D3vtr0n The suggestion of shortening the line is shorter, yes, but also far less readable.  I prefer Jimmeh's original answer with the full cmdlet names and parameters.

Comment: @pabrams Readable for whom? The compiler? Or humans? GCI is a common alias.

Comment: @D3vtr0n Readable by humans, and not PowerShell experts.  It's a fairly minor point, but published code, especially when used for purposes of instruction, should use full commandlet names, not aliases, as Jimmeh has done here.  He is completely correct to shy away from using aliases when answering questions (unless of course the question happens to ask for the alias), and you are incorrect for suggesting he replace the full commandlet names and parameters with aliases.

Comment: @D3vtr0n That doesn't follow (though I'll admit the first sentence of my last comment was not well crafted), and is incidental to the main point, which I'll assume you've finally understood, since you changed the subject instead of disputing it further.

Comment: @Jimmeh Thank you for using the long form when answering questions, its helpful when developers are starting out to see the "long-hand form" and recognize that they can alias away as they wish at a later date.

Comment: But this is also containing the wrong extensions.. for example if I have a folder named as "abc.foo" then it is taking .foo as extension which is wrong.. it should also check that it's type is not a folder but file..
EDIT: I have got my answer from @Esperento57, we should add `-File` key

Answer (score 13):

i complet solution of Jimmeh, use -file for take only file

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -Recurse -file | select directoryname, Extension -Unique
```

Comment: Up for `-File` key :) Because I have lots of `aaa.bbb` folders that produces tons of wrong extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Audio -Recurse | Group-Object psparentpath, extension | ? {(($_.Name -split ", .")[1]) -ne $Null } | ft -AutoSize @{Expression={(($_.Name.Split("\"))[$_.Name.Split("\").Length -1] -split ",")[0]};Label="Folder"}, @{Expression={($_.Name -split ", .")[1]};Label="Extension"}
```

To show full path to folder + extension, try the following.

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Audio -Recurse | Group-Object psparentpath, extension | ? {(($_.Name -split ", .")[1]) -ne $Null } | ft -AutoSize @{Expression={($_.Name.Replace("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::","") -split ", .")[0]};Label="Folder"}, @{Expression={($_.Name -split ", .")[1]};Label="Extension"}
```

Comment: forget this. Jimmeh made it look so easy :D